# Unable to pass 'this' value from one javascript function to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am calling a Javascript function from div onClick method

```
<div onClick="sample_1(this)" />
```

from this sample_1 method i am creating a new div dynamically and adding an onclick event in that div and trying to pass the value of 'this' got from the parameter of the sample_1 function but i am not able to pass the value of 'this' to the second method:

```
function sample_1 (divSelected) {
    if (!$(divSelected).attr('disabled')) {
       $('div[id=sample_1]').append("<div id='sample_1_1" + categoryID + "' class='selectedActivityCategory' style='background-color:#d9eaf7;' > <img  src='../Images/close.png' onclick='sample_2(" + divSelected.value + ");' /> </div>");
    }

}


function sample_2(divSelected)
{
/* Some Code */
}
```

When i am looking into IE developer tool then this dynamic div "sample_1_1" in its onClick method instead of passing the object divSelected value its just writing:

```
sample_2([object HTMLDivElement]);
```

How can i pass the object divSelected from sample_1 to sample_2?

I am trying to access the reference of the first div that is calling and passing its reference as this to method sample_1_1 and from there i am creating a new div and onclick event of that created div i am trying to pass the same reference of 1st div to the onclick method of the created div in sample_1_1 method.

Comment: div has not a `value` property. what do you expect to get with `divSelected.value` ?

Comment: You're doing a string concatenation when you define your onclick handler, it's not going to work.  Why pass it anyway?  Just use `this` again, and fetch `sample_1` by doing `divSelected.parentNode.parentNode`.

Comment: Lee Kowalkowski - actually div 'sample_1' is not the same div that is calling method 'sample_1' i need to pass the reference of that div to the next method. How can i achieve that?

Comment: To add:
Use `prop` in place of `attr` when dealing with boolean attributes.
e.g. `$(divSelected).prop('disabled')`

Comment: @BalrajSingh You cannot pass reference like this. `.html(<string>)` uses string but `this` is an object. Why not send id of other div instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do. The regular Javascript `this` does not have a `value` property.

If you are trying to get the contents of the div, you are mixing up `this` and `$(this)`, because through JQuery you **can** get the contents of a div (not through `value`) but by doing `$(this).html()`.

So a possible solution would be something like:

```
<div id="yourdiv">Content...</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#yourdiv').click(function() {
      sample_1($(this));
   });
});

function sample_1(div_selected) {
   alert("Contents are: " + div_selected.html());
}
```

I made you a small example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jk4Ut/)...

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, div element does not have a **value** property. If you want to access text within div use **innerHTML**. The parameter passing actually works fine, just check you if statement.

```
function sample_1 (divSelected) {
    alert(divSelected.innerHTML);
    sample_2(divSelected);

}


function sample_2(divSelected){
    /* Some Code */
    alert(divSelected.innerHTML);
}
```